# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my file name'

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

Помогите мне понять в чем соль этой ошибки:

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\Login form> python3
Python 3.9.10 (tags/v3.9.10:f2f3f53, Jan 17 2022, 15:14:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from orm_flask import db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'orm_flask(это имя моего файла)'
```

Сам код для соединения БД (postgresql) через ORM flask-sqlalchemy

Делала

```
pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy
```

потом update сделал все равно в ошибку.

My Script:

```
#Библиотеки

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import datetime
#
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:Password!@localhost:5432/postgres'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#
class TestUsers(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fullname = db.Column(db.String (50), nullable=False) 
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(),default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())

    def __init__(self,fullname,age):
        self.fullname = fullname
        self.age = age

etc
```

Занимаюсь в  VS Code / Pycharm у меня community версия и он сразу просит профессиональную ему установить для работы с flask

Comment: А где расположен файл `orm_flask.py`? И что вы из него импортировать пытаетесь - переменную?!

Comment: на рабочем столе

Comment: я пытаюсь к бд своей соединиться и создать там таблицу

Comment: Ну то есть эта строка `from orm_flask import db` выполняется в том же каталоге, где лежит файл `orm_flask`?

Comment: да! может тогда отдельно папку и туда файл и оттуда уже ранить? или переименовать для читаемости?

Comment: Перенесла все в одну папку, переименовала, теперь просто пишет >>> from main import db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\HTTP API\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'  Теперь flask не видит !!!